# Why didn't Fuyumi and Hydra Bell fuse like their mothers did?

Tags: blood-lad

From what I understand, When two opposite individuals (one from the human world and one from the demon world) touch each other, they are fused together to create one new individual that is made of the two of them.

So if Fuyumi and Hydra Bell are both the daughters of Nyen (Nene), why they didn't fuse when they touched each other?

Answer (score 3):

The straightforward answer to your question is that Fuyumi and Bell aren't doppelgangers ("opposites") for each other, and so there's no reason one should expect that they would fuse with each other.

Sure, their *mothers* were doppelgangers, but that doesn't mean that their children - Fuyumi and Bell - should also be. For one thing, they don't look very much like one another, whereas their mothers (pre-fusion) totally did:

[image]

Comment: If the common sense said (according to this series) every "coin" has two sides, then who would be better choice to be the other side of Fuyumi than Bell?

Comment: So it means that to have a doppelgangers their parent also need to have a doppelgangers and married with same doppelgangers? Am I said it right?

Comment: @ShinobuOshino I don't think so. Because then it's canceled the linear generation of all things. Basically two individuals never be doppelgangers because their parents didn't was doppelgangers and so on...

Comment: I guess the thing is that there's no reason that doppelgangers should have anything to do with genetics and/or familial relationships - as @HashiramaSenju points out, if you required "doppelganger-ness" to be transmitted by inheritance, you'd have entire family lines of doppelgangers, which doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score -2):

maybe the reason they didn't fuse when they were kids was because they were in the presence of another doppelganger fusion causing a energy thing.....

and why they don't fuse now is because fuyumi is a demon now so here and bell are not complete oposites anymore.... but if fuyumi is resurrected and bells in the rum they might fuse then.